# React - can't map through array - objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

My problem is that im trying to map through item.healthLabels using following code

```
{item.healthLabels.map((label) => ({ label }))}
```

The error I am getting is `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {label}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Then I have tried to display just the single label this way and it works fine

```
{item.healthLabels[0]}
```

What I have read is that I have to add `.toString()` however if I do `{item.healthLabels.map((label) => ({ label.toString() }))}`, the compiler won't even let me see the preview. It just doesn't accept this `.toString()`. Any solution?

healthLabels just seem to be a standard array like `0: "peanut-free", 1: "sugar-free"...`

Comment: Post what do you want the output to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to do `.map`, because you don't use the original values, but you wrap them in an object. Try just doing: `{item.healthLabels}` it should fix it.

The same code with `.map` must be modified so:

```
{item.healthLabels.map((label) =>  label )}
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 0):

In the working case you print a string while in the non-working version you try to print an object like `{label: 'some label value'}`.

Do not return an object from your map

```
{item.healthLabels.map((label) => ( label ))}
```

Comment: @ablaszkiewicz1 keep in mind though, that `{item.healthLabels.map((label) => ( label ))}` is the same as `{item.healthLabels}`. No need to map if you want to return the item in the array as is.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to return the value label as it is since it is of string type.

```
    const healthLabels = ["peanut-free", "sugar-free"];
    {healthLabels.map((label) => label )}
```